# OTRS and PyOTRS

Tags: python, django, otrs

Working with OTRS system with PyOTRS trying to create ticket. 
I get this message in response after I successfully create a ticket in the OTRS. I searched on the Internet for some people had a similar problem but found no solution anywhere.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
        six.raise_from(e, None)
      File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
        httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
        raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 357, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
        six.raise_from(e, None)
      File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
        httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
        raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyotrs/lib.py", line 1882, in _send_request
        verify=self.https_verify)
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
        raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "connetc.py", line 17, in <module>
        client.ticket_create(new_ticket, first_article)
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyotrs/lib.py", line 1125, in ticket_create
        if not self._parse_and_validate_response(self._send_request(payload)):
      File "/home/essaulov/try/try/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyotrs/lib.py", line 1891, in _send_request
        "Error with http communication: {0}".format(err))
    pyotrs.lib.HTTPError: Failed to access OTRS. Check Hostname, Proxy, SSL Certificate!
    Error with http communication: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```